# file permissions security apache

Tags: linux, apache, unix

I'm trying to figure out what is the best file permissions/user/groups for files under my document root?

I have the following file structure

```
/home/user/public_html/
```

under `public_html` are all of my php files and directories.

I have one directory `/home/user/public_html/files/` where people upload images to that directory.

What is the most secure way to distribute file permissions/groups/user so that apache can properly display the php files and directories?

Should I make `public_html` owned by apache? What group should I use for `public_html`?

thanks!

Comment: A better place to ask would be: http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Favourite mix of permissions for apache is to give it ownership of apache:apache, all folders chmod to 550 or 555, and all files chmod to 440/444. I suggest the following:

`/home/user/public_html/` owned by apache:apache with permissions 555 (read/x by everyone)
`/home/user/public_html/files/` owned by apache:apache with 775 (read/write/x by root/apache, read/x by all)

Comment: How does a user edit their files, if everything under `public_html` is owned by `apache:apache`?

Answer (score 0):

First need to find which user running https / apache2 server

```
ps -aux | grep apache2
```

Most of times apache or www-data comes

We need to set this user

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
```

Then file permission should be 644 and folder 755

we can do that using find command

```
find /var/www/html -type f -not -perm 644 -exec chmod 644 {} \;

find /var/www/html -type d -not -perm 755 -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```